# How to change ng-click to ng-touch in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have application in which i have written a numpad to entering user password. Using ng-click seems to be very slow in android based devices. I want to change these ng-click call into ng-touch to test a numpad button pressed event. Here is my code:

```
(function(){
    var numpad = function($log) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'partials/paddword.html',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

                scope.number = ngModel;

                scope.buttonPress = function(number) {
                    var value = scope.number.$viewValue || '';
                    scope.number.$setViewValue(value + number);
                };

                scope.remove = function() {
                    var value = scope.number.$viewValue || '';
                    if (value.length > 0) {
                        scope.number.$setViewValue(value.substring(0, value.length - 1));
                    }
                };

            }
        };
    };
    try {
        angular.module('myApplication').directive('numpad', numpad);

})();
```

and html look like this:

```
<div class="numpad" id="numpad" align="center">
    <div>
        <kbd data-ng-click="buttonPress(A)">A<div class="background">&nbsp;</div></kbd><kbd data-ng-click="buttonPress(B)">B</kbd>
    </div>
<div>
 <kbd data-ng-click="remove()">Delete</kbd> </div>
```

Can some one tell me how i can use ng-touch in this directive for buttonPress and remove function ?

Comment: I think the important question might be **why** is ng-click slow? It shouldnt be.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Well normally it should not but i have observe this on android phone and when i typing using this keys i can show almost 80% CPU on this device.